# Markdown.convert() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'text'

Tags: python, html, django, markdown

[Markdowner = Markdown.convert() [image ling]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGRaA.jpg)

Trying to convert markdown into HTML using Python's Markdown2 library,
However I keep getting the error -Markdown.convert() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'text'-

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a instance for `Markdown` then you can use `convert` method.

Example:

```
markdown = Markdown()
markdown.convert(your_text_goes_here)
```